# Terraform 0.15 - Multiple Providers \ Regions and Guardduty

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-guardduty

I’m trying to deploy AWS Guardduty using Organisations to multiple regions.

In my root config I’ve created the following provider:

```
    # If I remove this default provider out i get prompted for a region
    provider "aws" {
      profile = "default"
      region  = var.region
    }

    provider "aws" {
    
       profile = "default"
       alias   = "eu-west-2"
       region  = "eu-west-2"
    
    }
    
    provider "aws" {
    
      profile = "default"
      alias   = "eu-west-3"
      region  = "eu-west-3"
    
    }
```

then in my module call I have multiple calls to the module passing in my providers alias’s

```
module "guardduty_orgs_eu_west_2" {

  source = "../../modules/aws_guardduty_organisations"

  security_account_id = var.security_account_id

  providers = {

    aws.alternate = aws.eu-west-2

  }  

}

module "guardduty_orgs_eu_west_3" {

  source = "../../modules/aws_guardduty_organisations"

  security_account_id = var.security_account_id

  providers = {

    aws.alternate = aws.eu-west-3

  }  

}
```

In my module I then have the required providers block and ‘configuration_aliases’

```
terraform {

  required_providers {

    aws = {

      source  = "hashicorp/aws"

      version = "~> 3.27"

      configuration_aliases = [ aws.alternate ]

    }

  }

}
```

and finally my resource

```
resource "aws_guardduty_organization_admin_account" "gdoaa" {

  admin_account_id = var.security_account_id

  provider = aws.alternate

}
```

However, i get an error :

```
" Error: error enabling GuardDuty Organization Admin Account (123456789): BadRequestException: The request failed because the account is already enabled as the GuardDuty delegated administrator for the organization."
```

Now, this is correct as the first module call enables the Admin Account for “eu-west-2”, but i would think passing in the 2nd provider for “eu-west-3” would enable the Admin Account for this region as per the Guardduty best practices \ docs.

Any help appreciated

cheers

Paul

Answer (score 1):

```
/*resource "aws_guardduty_detector" "MyDetector" {
  enable = true
  datasources {
    s3_logs {
      enable = false
    }
    kubernetes {
      audit_logs {
        enable = false
      }
    }
  }
}
*/


resource "aws_guardduty_organization_configuration" "example" {
  provider = aws.securityacc
  auto_enable = true
  detector_id = "12345678"

}
```

this worked for me. hashout guardduty detector as it gets enabled already when you delegate it as a admin account.